How do you create a pivot table group by Date and perfom calculation on 2 values in pandas
I have this data frame:
df
Node      Interface    Speed   Band_In  carrier     Date
Server1   wan1         100     80       ATT         2024-06-01
Server1   wan2         100     60       Sprint      2024-06-01
Server1   wan3         100     96       Verizon     2024-06-01
Server2   wan1         100     80       ATT         2024-06-01
Server2   wan2         100     60       ATT         2024-06-01
Server2   wan3         100     96       ATT         2024-06-01
Server3   wan1         100     80       ATT         2024-06-01
Server3   wan2         100     60       ATT         2024-06-01
Server3   wan3         100     96       ATT         2024-06-01
Server4   wan1         100     80       ATT         2024-06-01
Server4   wan2         100     60       ATT         2024-06-01
Server5   Int3         100     96       Verizon     2024-06-01
Server1   wan1         100     30       ATT         2024-06-10
Server1   wan2         100     30       Sprint      2024-06-10
Server1   wan3         100     15       Verizon     2024-06-10
Server2   wan1         100     80       ATT         2024-06-10
Server2   wan2         100     60       ATT         2024-06-10
Server2   wan3         100     96       ATT         2024-06-10
Server3   wan1         100     80       ATT         2024-06-10
Server3   wan2         100     60       ATT         2024-06-10
Server3   wan3         100     96       ATT         2024-06-10
Server4   wan1         100     80       ATT         2024-06-10
Server4   wan2         100     60       ATT         2024-06-10
Server5   Int3         100     96       Verizon     2024-06-10

I need this data frame to be re-org where each uniq date needs to on its own column and used interface speed (Band_In/Speed)*100 calculated by each Node, Interface, Carier and Date (Date needs to be Month Name-Day: e.g. June-01, June-10)
In needs to be something like this:
df1:
Node      Interface    Speed   Band_In  carrier     1-Jun            10-Jun
Server1   wan1         100     80       ATT         80               30
Server1   wan2         100     60       Sprint      60               30
Server1   wan3         100     96       Verizon     96               15

I tried this:
 df1=df.pivot(index=['Node', 'Interface', 'Speed', 'Band_In', 'carrier'], columns='Date', values='Speed'/'Interface'*100).fillna('').reset_index()

I get length of passed values i 11,456, index implies 5.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

You can calculate used interface speed before pivoting the table, then use pivot_table:
df['is'] = df['Band_In'] / df['Speed'] * 100
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Node', 'Interface', 'carrier'], columns='Date', values='is').reset_index()

Date     Node Interface  carrier  2024-06-01  2024-06-10
0     Server1      wan1      ATT        80.0        30.0
1     Server1      wan2   Sprint        60.0        30.0
2     Server1      wan3  Verizon        96.0        15.0
3     Server2      wan1      ATT        80.0        80.0
4     Server2      wan2      ATT        60.0        60.0
5     Server2      wan3      ATT        96.0        96.0
6     Server3      wan1      ATT        80.0        80.0
7     Server3      wan2      ATT        60.0        60.0
8     Server3      wan3      ATT        96.0        96.0
9     Server4      wan1      ATT        80.0        80.0
10    Server4      wan2      ATT        60.0        60.0
11    Server5      Int3  Verizon        96.0        96.0


is there a way to rename the date formated column names to day-month name e.g 1-Jun, 10-Jun?

@user1471980 Yeah, you can use df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d-%b') before pivoting the table.

I know I accepted your answer, but quick question. Is there a way to sorty the Dates so that after pivot table, I see the dates in accesinding from left to right?

@user1471980 They should already be in ascending order, regardless of the original row order. If you mean descending, you can do df = df.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False) after pivoting.
